# add_rewrite_rule for custom sub pages

Tags: wordpress

For a plugin I need a `subpage` of a regular WordPress `page`. The normal `page` is located at

```
http://example.com/page
```

To get a `subpage`

```
http://example.com/page/subpage
```

I'm using the rewrite_rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/(subpage|subpage2|subpage3|subpage4)', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&_mysubpage=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

This **is working** fine until I move the `page` to a `parent` page:

```
http://example.com/parentpage/page/subpage
```

or if I set the `page` as homepage

```
http://example.com/subpage
```

Which additional `add_rewrite_rule` do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution but if anyone have a better feel free to share.

**1) The Subpage**

The `pagename` on a subpage is `page/subpage` so the initial `add_rewrite_rule` become

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(.+)/(subpage|subpage2|subpage3|subpage4)', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&_mysubpage=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

**2) The Homepage**

For the homepage you need the ID of the `page` and an additional `add_rewrite_rule`

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^(subpage|subpage2|subpage3|subpage4)', 'index.php?page_id={YOUR_PAGE_ID}&_mysubpage=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

note that pagename get's replaced with page_id